# Use interrupts with python with Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, interrupt

I have a little problem here I hope you can help me. 
I need to interrupt the main thread of my program but I don't want to run a new thread. I just want to when I press a button cause an interruption of the main thread.
I have read this post http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interru ... pio-part-3 but neither of the options that mention there works for me.
I've also read something about using wiringpi2 library, precisely the function wiringPiISR. But every time I execute my code, no matter if the button is pressed or not, the function my_callback executes anyway.

```
wpi = wiringpi2.GPIO(wiringpi2.GPIO.WPI_MODE_PINS)
wpi.pullUpDnControl(2,wpi.PUD_UP) 
wpi.wiringPiISR(2, wpi.INT_EDGE_RISING, my_callback())
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Marina, you mention a link -- is your issue related to making GPIO module imports working on your RPi, or is your issue related to successfully cross-validated installation ( conform to the RPi.GPIO 0.5.1 ) but failing to handle the hardware interrupts? Making your post equipped with a MCVE -- a [M]inimum-[C]omplete-[V]erifiable-[E]xample -- would also help other StackOverflow Nerds drill into details needed to make your code work ( Try to re-read about StackOverflow Netiquette on MCVE and how to ask better questions & enjoy being an actively contributing member here )